# How to deal with functions without real root, when using the Newton Method

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to modify a code, that I was able to build with the help of different members, in such a way that if a function has no roots, it generates a message that says so, and if it does, it gives the result. The code is the following:

```
NewtonRoot[function_, initialValue_, tolerance_, iterationMax_] :=
 Module[
  {p, data, n},
  p[0] = initialValue;
  vk = Table[
    p[n + 1] = N[p[n] - f[p[n]]/f'[p[n]]]; {n, p[n]},
    {n, 0, iterationMax}]; 
  Print[
   If[
    f[vk[[-1, -1]]] >= tolerance,
    StringForm[
     "Newton's method found no roots near `` after `` iterations", 
     initialValue, iterationMax],
    StringForm["The function has a possible root near ``: ``", 
     initialValue, vk[[-1, -1]]]]];
  Array[p, iterationMax]]
```

When f[x]=x^2*(x-2) and I give as initial value i.e 1.6 I get as a result that the value is 2.

When i give as an initial value i.e 0.1 , it says that there is a solution but it's not exactly zero but close to it and I don't understand why it doesn't give me 0 exactly.

But the main problem is for example a function like g[x]=x^2+1. It doesn't work for this function. I don't get a warning that says that the function has no roots.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've hard-coded the name of the function `f` in your code, so it won't work with `g`. Note that your first parameter `function` is never used in your code.

Comment: but I have used the underscore i.e function_

Comment: Change `function_` to `f_` in the definition, then pass in the expressions as pure functions: `NewtonRoot[#^2 + 1 &, 2, 0.01, 10]`.

Comment: A function such as `x^2-c` has 0, 1 or 2 roots depending on whether c is positive, negative or zero.  Numerically, distinguishing between these 3 cases is very hard (for small `c`).  It is the repeated root problem.  Graphically, you can think of the Newton method as drawing a tangent and seeing where it intersect the horizontal axis.  Near the minimum the tangent will be close to horizontal and the intersection can take you a long way from the root.  Other techniques will also struggle, but may be more robust.

Comment: With respect to your other question ("why it doesn't give me 0 exactly"), there is round-off error in computing both `x` and `f[x]`. The round-off in `x` might be corrected in the next Newton step; but the exact solution may not exist among the floating point numbers, and `x` might be rounded to the nearest binary fraction. Example: 1/10 does not exist: `Table[100 x^2 - 1, {x, 0.1 - 2^-54, 0.1 + 2^-54, 2^-56}]`. In this `Table[]`, the round-off error in `x` is magnified by `f[x]`, and none of the values of `f[x]` is zero exactly.

Comment: Your function will produce no output if the function `f[x]` does not give real numeric output when `x` is a real number. If you add a fourth argument to `If[]`, you'll get output: `If[f[vk[[-1, -1]]] >= tolerance, ..., ..., 
 StringForm["There's a proble with f: `` is not a real number", 
  f[vk[[-1, -1]]]]]`.  This would help you debug your code or input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function has several problems. Here is a cleaned up version (I assume that you are only after real roots):

```
NewtonRoot[f_, initialValue_, tolerance_, iterationMax_] := 
 Module[{iter},
  iter = NestList[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, initialValue, iterationMax];
  Print[If[f[iter[[-1]]] >= tolerance, 
    StringForm[
     "Newton's method found no roots near `` after `` iterations", 
     initialValue, iterationMax], 
    StringForm["The function has a possible root near ``: ``", 
     initialValue, f[iter[[-1]]]]]];
  iter]
```

Here are the results:

```
fun[x_] = x (x - 2);
NewtonRoot[fun, 1.6, 10^-2, 10]
```

[image]

```
NewtonRoot[fun, 0.1, 10^-2, 10]
```

[image]

```
fun[x_] = x^2 + 1;
NewtonRoot[fun, 1.6, 10^-2, 10]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have one further question. Is it possible to use the newton method or even the Bisection method, without specifying that determine precision and step size, while assuming we choose reasonable initial values?

Comment: You do not need to specify a step size. You can give the precision a default value like e.g.: "NewtonRoot[... tolerance_:10^-6..]:=.." For safety, I would define a max. iteration number. BTW: Bisection or Secant are  saver methods. Newton can go astray if the initial value is bad.